# how do I insert a 2d Javascript array into mysql table

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, database

I want to insert a 2d array (if we consider it as a table) and it can have any number of rows but a fixed umber of defined columns
so how do insert this into a mysql table

```
var myArr = [
  [ 10000, '2021-03-08', 10000, '2021-03-07', 0, 364 ],
  [ 10000, '2021-04-08', 10000,'2021-03-08', 0, 333 ],
  [ 10000, '2021-05-08', 5000, '2021-03-08', 2500, 303 ]
]

sql = 'INSERT INTO vm001 (Amount, date, entryamt, entrydate, balanceamt, daysdel) VALUES ?'

db.query(sql , myArr , function (err) {
   console.log(err)
})
```

this is what I tried but it didn't work so can anyone suggest a way to make this work
this is the console

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10000, '2021-03-08', 10000, '2022-03-07', 0, 364' at line 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem was a simple square bracket

```
db.query(sql , [myArr] , function (err) {
   console.log(err)
})
```

this solves the problem

```
myArr to [myArr]
```